# Pushing an extra field into an array in Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am returning project team member details.

The tables involved are:

```
 users
 projects 
 members
```

(edited for brevity they look like this)

```
'users'
    ('id',
    'name',
    'email',
    'avatar',
    'avatar_type',
    'status')

'projects'
    ('id',
    'name',
    'description')

'members'
    ('id',
    'user_id',
    'position',
    'capacity')
```

Projects can have multiple members and the members table is effectively a pivot table for the users.

Currently using this:

```
$projectTeam = [];
$project[0]->members()
    ->with('users')
    ->where('user_id','!=',0)
    ->where('status','=',"Active")
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($member) use(&$projectTeam)
    {
        $projectTeam[$member->id] = $member->users;
    });
```

What I would like to do in the loop above is to evaluate the user record and then if the avatar field is populated and the avatar type is a certain value create/push/append another field into the results so that I can add in extra information.

Something like this:

```
$projectTeam = [];
$project[0]->members()
    ->with('users')
    ->where('status','=',"Active")
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($member) use(&$projectTeam)
    {
        $projectTeam[$member->id] = $member->users;

            if($member->users->avatar<>"")
            {
                if($member->users->avatar-type=="1")
                {
                    array_push($projectTeam[$member->id], "imgClass='alpha'")
                }
                if($member->users->avatar-type=="2")
                {
                    array_push($projectTeam[$member->id], "imgClass='beta'")
                }
            }
    });
```

So that when I call those image records on the front end I can just populate the html class with that new field.

Something like this:

```
<img src="{{$teammember->avatar}}" class="{{$teammember->imgClass" />
```

Hope this makes sense!

How do I go about adding in that extra field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$projectTeam[$member->id]->imgClass = 'alpha'
```

Comment: Thanks, with that I get an error "Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: Perhaps I need to somehow declare that new field?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I had moved things around - all sorted now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

And now for the **real** Eloquent answer...

What you want to do is do

```
class ProjectTeam
{
    protected $appends = ['imageClass'];

    public function getImageClassAttribute()
    {
        return 'whatever';
    }
}
```

Now whenever you call `$projectTeam->imageClass`, you'll get `whatever`.

Comment: Looks like a good way to go! So in the function getImageClassAttribute would I then evaluate the $member->users->avatar field and return the appropriate class?

Comment: Yeah but you might be better suited with a proper Eloquent relationship... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships